# Updating Dictionary Values after For Loop in Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not really sure if this question has been asked before but... I need help to update the dictionary values after I have added them to the "value" in the dictionary. Please help!

```
import csv

    with open('USVideos.csv', encoding="utf-8") as file:

    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    header = next(reader)
    youtube_usa_videos = []

    for row in reader:
        youtube_usa_videos.append(row)

Unique_channels = []
for list in youtube_usa_videos:
    if list[2] in Unique_channels:
        continue
    else:
        Unique_channels.append(list[2])
Like_per_channel = dict((channel, 0) for channel in Unique_channels)

for (key, value) in Like_per_channel.items():
    for list in youtube_usa_videos:
        if list[2] == key:
            value += int(list[7])
        else:
            continue
    print(Like_per_channel)
```

How do I update the value in the "Like_per_channel.items()"  after finding the unique key for the value I want to increase?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you correct the indent of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if list[2] == key:
    value += int(list[7])
```

Use:

```
if list[2] == key:
    Like_per_channel[key] += int(list[7])
```

Its not a good idea to update a dictionary that is being traversed. You could create a copy and update that instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your comment! I am one step closer to finding my results haha may I ask why would it not be a good idea to update the dictionary?

Comment: Refer [this](https://unspecified.wordpress.com/2009/02/12/thou-shalt-not-modify-a-list-during-iteration/) article. Although it is for lists, the same principle applies here